# toString in java - System.out.println vs log in Android

Tags: java, android, printing, tostring

Lets assume i have the following class definition:

```
class Test{
    public String toString(){

        return "hello test";
    }
```

Now from another class i do the following:

```
Test myTest=new Test();
//output of below will be 'hello test'
System.out.println(myTest);
```

I am looking for the equivalent in Android so i could do something like this on objects:

```
Log.d("TAG",myTest);  
or even createToast(Context,myTest,Toast.short).show();
```

I dont want to have to call the objects toString method, i just want to dump the object into the method and it knows it needs to call toString just like system.out.println did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since Log.X only takes a String as second parameter, you'd better do a wrapper that calls the Android logger, something like:

```
static class MyLogger{
        public static void d(String tag,Object o){
            if(o==null){
                throw new NullPointerException("The second parameter can not be null");
            }
            Log.d(tag, o.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: yah i just noticed system.out.println has an overload for object.  Im a little slow this morning, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

adding an object to a string will adds its "toString" method without your call to it

```
Log.d("TAG", "" + myTest);
```

or even

```
createToast(Context, "" + myTest,Toast.short).show();
```

Comment: as a second option you have to override the log.d or makeText

Comment: im refactoring code to make it more clean and less smells.  This is not what i want to do but thank you. I think the issue is closed now.